# FIlling a character array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array one character at a time, then print it out one character at a time, but when I input 5 letters, it cuts to the print statement, and prints a bunch of garbage values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char work[10];
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
       work[i] = getchar();
    }

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%c\n",work[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample run? It seems to behave as expected for me.

Comment: no, it works if don't use unicode

Comment: Please read [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and include example input/output. Your problem may be that you're using Unicode, but nobody know for sure.

Comment: Are you entering the five letters by pressing the ENTER key after each? That would be the obvious reaon why it would do as you suggest, since each of the ENTER key presses is a character in itself.

Comment: Btw just initialize the char array. for e.g   `char work[10] = "";`

Comment: The only problems I see are 1) unnecessary 1st initialization `i` to `0`, 2)   `main()` should return an `int` value (eg `0`), none of which affect the algo behavior

Comment: @RingØ: actually, that last one isn't a problem as of C11, `main` implicitly returns zero if it reaches the closing brace. But your comment is spot on, neither issue is likely to affect the character I/O and/or loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char work[10];
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
       work[i] = getchar();
    }

    for(i = 0;i<10;i++){
        putchar(work[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Answer with only code and "try this" are often not helpful. Explain what have you changed and why.

Comment: Also -- for unclear question, it's better to flag the question as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: I'm not convinced that replacing `printf("%c\n", someChar)` with `putchar(someChar)` is going to make much difference.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe "\n" is automatically added when getchar() is called. Use "./exec | cat -e" to see them.

So Set char work[20] and i<20.